# Regarding a doubt in proof of prime number theorem( related to showing convergence of improper integral)

Tags: number-theory, improper-integrals, analytic-number-theory

While self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol I have a doubt in Ch-13 ( Analytic proof of Prime number theorem)  I am having problem in how to show convergence of improper integral

Images  ->
[image]

> Can someone please tell how this integral from e to $\infty$  converges ie which result is used by Apostol to prove it. Although I had earlier went through its proof but I couldn't recollect now how I proved its convergence  .

Please help.

Comment: Make the substitution $u=log \, t$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy can it also be proved by comparing with 1 / t^{3/2} ?

Comment: Yes, if you know that $\frac {(\log \, t)^{9}} {\sqrt t}$ is bounded.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy  I am sorry I made a mistake. I was assuming that I will divide it by 1/t^{3/2} , but then limit comparison test will not prove divergence or convergence as limit =0 .

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy after substituting u= log t, what test should I apply , can you please tell?

Comment: You will get $\int_1^{\infty} u^{9} e^{-u} du$. Use the fact that $e^{u} >\frac {u^{11}} {(11)!}$.